# HAPI 2 v2.3 - setValidating(false) has no impact on XMLParser

Tags: java, hapi

with the latest version of HAPI 2 v2.3, turn off the validation only works for the pipedParser, the XMLParser has no impact.

the sample codes below works fine with the previous version (HAPI 2 v2.2), but with HAPI v2.3, it throws an exception:

- *Validation failed: Primitive value 'THIS-IS-NOT-DATE-VALUE' requires to be empty or a HL7 datetime string*

  ```
  import ca.uhn.hl7v2.DefaultHapiContext;
  import ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception;
  import ca.uhn.hl7v2.HapiContext;
  import ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.Message;
  import ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.PipeParser;
  import ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.XMLParser;

  public class TestXMLParser {    
     public static void main(String[] args) throws HL7Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String invalidMessage = "MSH|^~\\&|MedSeries|CAISI_1-2|PLS|3910|200903230934||ADT^A31^ADT_A05|75535037-1237815294895|P^T|2.4\r"
                         + "EVN|A31|THIS-IS-NOT-DATE-VALUE\r"
                         + "PID|1||29^^CAISI_1-2^PI~\"\"||Test300^Leticia^^^^^L||19770202|M||||||||||||||||||||||";

            HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();
            // turn off the validation <<<<<<<<<<<<<<=================
            context.getParserConfiguration().setValidating(false);

            Message hapiMsg = null;
            String xmlDoc = null;

            // get an instance of the PipeParser
            PipeParser parser = context.getPipeParser();
            hapiMsg = parser.parse(invalidMessage); // this works fine
            System.out.println("Successfully parsed the message");

            // get an instance of XMLParser
            XMLParser xmlParser = context.getXMLParser();

            // encode the piped formatted message to xml format
            xmlDoc = xmlParser.encode(hapiMsg);

            // try to parse the xml string into Hapi message objects
            Message xmlMessage = xmlParser.parse(xmlDoc);// with HAPI 2 v2.3 an exception is thrown.

            // encode the xml formatted message to pipe-format
            String er7 = parser.encode(xmlMessage);
            System.out.println("er7:\n" + er7);
     }
  ```

  }

I wonder if you have any suggestions/work around.
Thanks.

Comment: in case someone looking for the solution, you can find the fix here: https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-hl7v2/commit/f17db02ce8bcfd5df25a894039186719c432df3e thanks.